# How do I import a number from a session query in PowerShell/CMD

Tags: python, powershell, import, scripting, rdp

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that allows me to query a user session and shadow said session in RDP. I want to pull the active session from `qwinsta`, however I can only pull down a result if I input credentials for my domain inserted. Here's an example of what I mean within PowerShell:

`runas /user:DOMAIN\USER "cmd /k qwinsta /server:192.168.255.2"`

will output

`SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID   STATE`

`services                                    0   Disc`

`console           jdoe                      2   Active`

`rdp-tcp                                 65536   Listen`

This will pull up cmd and allow me to see the output of the query. However, I don't want to do this every time I have to remote in because it is tedious. I am very brand new to PowerShell so please forgive my ignorance, but how can I pull the ID number of jdoe (in this case, the number 2), import it into Powershell in maybe the form of a variable/string such as `$activeSession =`, then run the script like so

`Mstsc /shadow:$activeSession /v:192.168.255.2 /control /NoConsentPrompt /prompt`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can do `(qwinsta) -match '\b\d+\s+Active\b' -replace '\D'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `ID` of `Active` sessions, you can do the following:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\USER "cmd /a /c qwinsta /server:192.168.255.2 > c:\temp\sessions.txt"
$activeSession = (Get-Content c:\temp\sessions.txt) -match '\b\d+\s+Active\b' -replace '\D'
```

The `cmd qwinsta` command will output to a file `sessions.txt`. Then you can use `Get-Content` to read the file and parse the data you want.

`-match` and `-replace` are [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) that use regex to match strings. `\b` is a word boundary. `\d+` is one or more digits. `\D` is any non-digit. Since `-replace` has no replacement string, any matched characters are removed.

---

A more PowerShell solution could utilize [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7):

```
$sessions = Invoke-Command -Scriptblock {qwinsta} -Credential Domain\User -ComputerName 192.168.255.2
$activeSession = $sessions -match '\b\d+\s+Active\b' -replace '\D'
```

This would require [PSRemoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7) to be configured.

Comment: Thankfully I realized my device had local admin on and powershell wasn't taking my domain creds as a result. Qwinsta can be used within powershell now, and I took a function from PoSh Wolf called Get-ActiveSessions; I'm closer to my desired result. If you'd like, you can check out the new post on my profile. Thanks for your help!